# can we used world update for France only server ? seems to make wrong query result

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

On my local overpass api server with **only french data** on which is applied hourly planet diff, some of the query responses are wrong.

It's not doing it for each query : but something like once every 200 requests , sometime more ...

for example :

```
[timeout:360][out:json];way(48.359900103518235,5.708088852670471,48.360439696481784,5.708900947329539)[highway];out ;
```

return 3 ways :

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.54.13 ff15392f",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-09-23T15:00:00Z",
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "way",
      "id": 53290349,
      "nodes": [...],
      "tags": {
        "highway": "secondary",
        "maxspeed": "100",
        "ref": "L 385"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "way",
      "id": 238493649,
      "nodes": [...],
      "tags": {
        "highway": "residential",
        "name": "Rue du Stand",
        "ref": "C 3",
        "source": "..."
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "way",
      "id": 597978369,
      "nodes": [...],
      "tags": {
        "highway": "service"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

First one is in Germany, far East ...

My question :

- On an overpass api server, is there a way to apply diff only for defined area ? it is not documented ( neither here : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation
  or here : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Breki/Overpass_API_Installation#Configuring_Diffs )
- if not, how to get rid of those wrong results ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need some external tool to preprocess your diff files, you cannot do this on Overpass API.

Comment: i found that there is French diff file existing : [http://download.openstreetmap.fr/replication/europe/france/minute/]

so i will restart my server with those diffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two questions, so two answer :

- i found that there is French diff file existing : http://download.openstreetmap.fr/replication/europe/france/minute/ so i will restart my server with those diffs.
- The best way to get rid of those wrong result is to have a consistant server : no world diff for just France Data.